# How can I convert date to string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert it in a simple way using str() but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
import json
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    lastUpdate="2020-09-17 03:59:21+00:00"
    now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
    diff = now - lastUpdate
    print("Now:" + str(now) + lastUpdate)
```

Output:
errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype of 'now' is datetime and of 'lastUpdate' is str, you cannot get difference between different datatypes. Convert lastUpdate to datetime format first.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil import parser

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  lastUpdate="2020-09-17 03:59:21+00:00"
  lastUpdate = parser.parse("2020-09-17 03:59:21+00:00")
  now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
  diff = now - lastUpdate
  print("Now:" + str(now) + str(lastUpdate))
```

Answer (score 2):

get the utc timezone and string format as below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

lastUpdate="2020-09-17 03:59:21+00:00"
now2 = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y%m%d  %H:%M:%S")

print("Now:" + str(now2) + lastUpdate)
```

for the differences, please parse string into two datetime objects and calculate the differences in days.

```
now3 = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

day = datetime.strptime(lastUpdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

print("now3= "+ str(now3))
print("day= " +  str(day))
      
diffs = now3 - day

print('Total difference in minutes: ', str(diffs.days))

print("Now:" + str(now3) +" "+ lastUpdate + "Diff= " + str(diffs.days))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do as you do, I get `"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'"`. I didn't put diff variable here as it had no issue. How can I resolve this? `print("Now:" + now + "LastModified:" + obj['LastModified'] + "Diff=" + diff)`

Comment: Change everthing into string, Mostlikely your now and diff stil in datetime format. just use str( ) on the datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

[strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

[strftime-and-strptime-format-codes](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
from datetime import datetime

lastUpdate = "2020-09-17 03:59:21+00:00"
dt: datetime = datetime.strptime(lastUpdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 17, 3, 59, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

dt_str = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(repr(dt_str))
# '2020-09-17 03:59:21'
```